# Vuejs total variable for cart returning NaN

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a cart system using vuejs and wanted to know why my total variable is returning NaN instead of calculating the total price of all products.

This is the total function

```
total: function(){
    var tot = 0;
    for ( var product in this.products){
        tot += product.price;
    }
    return tot;
}
```

And this is how I display it in my template

```
total: {{total}}
```

Comment: 2 things have you tested to see if your products array contains any elements. Also if this is going to prod please don't do floating point math with money `.1 + .1 + .1 !== .3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for in` loop is used to loop object properties, not array, read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

you can loop arrays with it but you're getting the index of the product, not the product itself. so when you do `tot += product.price;` you're adding 0 (first value of `tot`) and `undefined` and that gives you `NaN`

use [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method for your case like this

```
total: function(){
  let tot = 0;
  this.products.forEach(product => tot += product.price)
  return tot;
}
```

With reduce rather then `forEach()`

```
total: function(){
  return this.products.reduce((tot, product) => tot += product.price, 0)
}
```

Comment: I think I would use a reduce over a `forEach()` here as `forEach()` is meant to mutate the state of every element in an Array well a `reduce()` is meant to produce a sum.

Comment: `forEach` is just sugar for good old `for loop`, it won't mutate anything unless you make it mutate. here, I'm just adding a price of each product to `tot` variable, not mutating the prices.

Comment: I'm aware that this call doesn't mutate the state of any elements in the array. I'm just pointing out that `forEach` is meant to be used to mutate the state of the elements in an array. Well `reduce` is meant to create a new variable in this case the `tot` variable.

Comment: I would also suggest that you take a look at reduce as this is the kind of thing it was built for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

How about try to debug it by yourself like

```
  for ( var product in this.products){
    console.log(product);
    tot += product.price;
}
```

and you will find out `product` is enumerable property of `this.products`,
if `this.products` is a Array, it will outputs `0`, `1`, `2`, .... , you can find better understanding of [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) here.

So, if you insist use `for..in`, you'd better change to

```
tot += this.products[product].price;
```

or you have better choice with `reduce` to sum values.

```
tot: function (){
    var tot = 0;
    tot = this.products.reduce((pre, next) => {
        return pre += next.price;
    }, tot);
    return tot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If above answers don't work, try changing the return statement to:

```
return tot || 0
```